# Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 couldn't find Model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

okay, I'm a newbie to Rails and I don't have too much experience with coding in general, so maybe this seems stupid, but here's my problem:

**I edited the code, so here is an update of my current status, including more information:**

Voting & Option Model:

```
class Voting < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :options
  validates :vote, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voting
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :votings do
    resources :options
  end
  root 'votings#new'
end
```

votings/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>create new poll</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :voting, url: votings_path, local: true do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :voting %><br>
      <%= form.text_area :content %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.fields_for :option do |option| %>
          <%= option.label 'Optionen' %><br>
          <%= option.text_field :vote %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

votings/show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Your Voting:</strong>
  <%= @voting.content %>
</p>
<ul>
  <p>
  <%= @options.vote %>
  </p>
</ul>
```

votings_controller.rb:

```
 class VotingsController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @voting = Voting.find(params[:id])
        @options = @voting.options
      end

      def new
        @voting = Voting.new
        @voting.options.build
  end

  def create
    @voting = Voting.new(voting_params)
    @voting.save
    redirect_to @voting
  end

  private
  def voting_params
    params.require(:voting).permit(:content, options_attributes: [:id, :vote])
  end
end
```

options_controller.rb:

```
class OptionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @voting = Voting.find(params[:id])
    @options = @voting.options.create(option_params)
    redirect_to voting_path(@voting)
  end

  private
  def option_params
    params.require(:option).permit(:vote)
  end
end
```

(I think some of the code in the options controller double with the votings controller and I'm not even sure if it's needed).

So, I want to create a voting with its associated options within the same page and after that show the voting with its options on the same page (voting/new.html.erb & voting/show.html.erb).

This is my current error message:

> NoMethodError in VotingsController#create
>
> undefined method `vote' for #Voting:0x0000000be55208

(this shows up after submitting the content from the form.)
So, the form new.html.erb works fine so far.

It seems that he doesn't know what to do the 'vote' in

```
<%= @options.vote %>
```

from the show.html.erb

I hope the further information will help getting this problem solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't get options right"? What error/unexpected behaviour do you see? What does the log show?

Comment: at the moment, it's "Couldn't find Option with 'id'=30"
it seems he doesn't like the show action, but I'm not sure if this is the source of the problem

Comment: How are you getting option_id 30? may be option with id 30 is already deleted

Comment: You said "Everything works fine for just creating and showing". Now you say "it seems he doesn't like the show action". So I'm confused what you're saying is broken. However, this line: `@option = Option.find(params[:id])` looks dubious to me since this is the `VotingsController`; I'd expect `params[:id]` to be the `Voting` id, not the `Option` id.

Comment: @TomLord Yes, it worked fine for creating and showing a VOTING, but since I added the option part (option belongs_to voting) it fails.

Comment: Oh, right... So a previous version of the code (that you haven't shown) is what works :) -- I go back to my previous comment then: The `params[:id]` is presumably the `Voting` id; you're searching for the wrong thing. In addition, if a `Voting` has **many** `options`, then you need to update the UI to show *all* of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit scarce on details, so I'll just point out the obvious and hope it helps.

Your voting controller show action uses what a resourceful app would expect to be a **voting** object ID to find an **option** object.

```
class VotingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @option = Option.find(params[:id]) # In a resource route this is a voting id!
    @voting = @option.user # what is option.user? Should be option.voting?
  end
```

This assumes your routes file defines `resources :votings` ?

Comment: thank you, at first. 
okay, that "user" thing shouldn't be there at all, I think I was too tired yesterday... I tried out so many different things, it seems to be a leftover of shame, I'm sorry! I edited it out to avoid further confusion. 
And yes, my routes file defines `resourses:votings`.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain your problem as simple answer hopefully it will help you debug your doubt.

```
  def create
    @voting = Voting.new(voting_params)

    @voting.save
    redirect_to @voting
  end
```

in this action after creating `@voting` it been redirected to `show` action as `redirect_to @voting` which will create a link link this

```
/voting/:id
```

here in show action we are sending voting's id, so its clear straight that in `show` action when we will try to get `params[:id]` it will be voting's id not the option's id
basically here it should be

```
  def show
    @voting = Voting.find(params[:id])
    @options = @voting.options
  end
```

hopefully it will help you to debug your doubt, i m not sure what you what, let me know for further guidance. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are trying to show voting model with it's options.

So the RESTful URL is `/voting/<voting_id>`. If options are included in routes.rb as nested resource to Voting, to show a particular option, it is `/voting/<voting_id>/options/<option_id>`

For example, in `localhost:3000/voting/1/options/20`

> 1 is the id of voting and 20 is the id of option

So you need to change show method as:

```
def show
    @voting = Voting.find(params[:id])
    @options = @voting.options # Here it fetches all options for voting of the id passed 
end
```

I'd also suggest modifying the voting_params method as:

```
def vote_params
    params.require(:voting).permit(:content, options_attributes: [:id, :vote])
end
```

As you have multiple options for a single voting, you need to whitelist the id of every option, else it'll override. You can read more on this [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

The model association you have is very similar to the example in **[rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model)**. Read it and reuse the code for a start.

**EDIT:**

I suggest using form_for(is soft-deprecated in rails 5) instead of form_with for things to work, for now.
Your votings/new.html.erb will look like:

```
<h1>create new poll</h1>

<%= <%= form_for @voting do |form| %> %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :voting %><br>
      <%= form.text_area :content %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.fields_for :option do |option| %>
          <%= option.label 'Optionen' %><br>
          <%= option.text_field :vote %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Using form_with simply like this didn't work for me as auto-generation of ids is not supported with form_with. But hold on to your refactoring until rails 5.2 releases and form_for can be replaced with form_with. This is an inference from [this rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3893ec38ec61282c2598b01a298124356d6b35a)

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are right, I want to create the Voting with its Options one the same new.html.erb page and then show the Voting with its Options on the same show.html.erb...
I think your answer is leading into the right direction, but it still won't work. (I also went through your linked rails guides again).
I will edit the question to update it to my current status and add more detailed information.

Comment: Use form_for instead of form_with to get things working for now. But be aware that form_with is soft-deprecated, that is, form_for will not be supported in future rails' version. I have edited the original answer with the working solution.